# Django form validate unique_together

Tags: django, forms, validation, unique

Need to stop user from creating record with same data so:

in ** models.py **  I've added:

```
class Materiale(models.Model):
  class Meta:
  unique_together = (("data_rif","causale","rapp_rif", "articolo","qta", "nota"),)
```

this is what I've added in ** form.py**:

```
class CreaMaterialeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Materiale
    fields = ('articolo','qta','udm')
    error_messages = {
        NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
            'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
        }
    }
```

but every time I submit duplicate data, I get to the django error screen of:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError
>
> IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: mat_app_materiale.DATA_RIF,
>   mat_app_materiale.CAUSALE, mat_app_materiale.rapp_rif_id,
>   mat_app_materiale.ARTICOLO, mat_app_materiale.QTA,
>   mat_app_materiale.NOTA

```
File ".virtualenvs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
 line 323, in execute
         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
     IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: mat_app_materiale.DATA_RIF, mat_app_materiale.CAUSALE,
 mat_app_materiale.rapp_rif_id, mat_app_materiale.ARTICOLO,
 mat_app_materiale.QTA, mat_app_materiale.NOTA
```

If it goes here means that form has been validated and submitted to db. So something is missing,Is there something else to allow form to return error message instead to access django.db.utils.IntegrityError error screen?

The **view** is :

```
class MaterialeCreate(CreateView): 
    form_class = CreaMaterialeForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.data_rif=form.cleaned_data['data_rif']

    rapportino_rif = Rapporto.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['rapp_rif'])
    form.instance.rapp_rif=rapportino_rif
```

Comment: Please show the full error.

Comment: The problem is that not all of the fields from the `unique_together` are used in the form, so the form does not check the constraint. Please show your view that uses the form.

Comment: if form_valid is defined in the view, and I add parameter there, this could invalidate the behavior of unique_togheter check in form?